# Query from Kusto to PowerBI

Tags: powerbi-desktop, azure-data-explorer

there are 2 different experiences i have seen while using "Query to PowerBI" from tools menu in kusto explorer. [image of both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7NvP.png)

I am getting the fist one, but want to use second one(query? with additional details/options). How do i get it in second format

Answer (score 0):

You can control the behavior of PowerBI query using Tools->Options->Tools->PowerBI Export To Native Connector.

[image]